# Payments in local currency in Software Centre

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

I'm from the UK and buying software from the Software Centre in USD incurs charges from my bank. Are there any plans to allow payments in local currency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each currency we implement needs to be supported by our credit card payment provider.  This sometimes includes country-specific technical requirements - in the case of GBP, supporting 3D secure.  So, in answer to your question, we are planning to support GBP soon and will add other currencies based on payment provider support, user demand and effort to implement.

Support for 3D Secure is being tracked on http://pad.lv/656929 so feel free to subscribe to that bug and add your '+1' ("Also affects me") to it.

Comment: And I think PayPal support may help you out as well. Watch for that soon!